# MySql SELECT DISTINCT two column same table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch the IDs(foreign keys) of other person who are parallel to ID 51.

```
ID | name   | sender_id | reciever_id | time
1  | hjhjnk | 51        | 2           | SOMETIME
2  | hjhjnk | 2         | 51          | SOMETIME
3  | hjhjnk | 51        | 2           | SOMETIME
4  | hjhjnk | 51        | 2           | SOMETIME
5  | hjhjnk | 51        | 3           | SOMETIME
6  | hjhjnk | 6         | 51          | SOMETIME
7  | hjhjnk | 55        | 2           | SOMETIME
```

Currently i have to use Queries twice.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `reciever_id` FROM `message` WHERE `sender_id` LIKE 51
SELECT DISTINCT `sender_id` FROM `message` WHERE `reciever_id` LIKE 51
```

So that i can have 2,3 and 6.
Can i single Query achieve this, If yes then how, If not then why not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to combine them into a single query is to use union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `reciever_id` FROM `message` WHERE `sender_id` =51
Union
SELECT DISTINCT `sender_id` FROM `message` WHERE `reciever_id` =51
```

You could use conditional expressions in the select list and `or` condition in the where clause as well, but that would be really ineffective from a performance point of view.

Comment: Thanks, but it is only giving 2,3 from receiver_id nothing from sender_id.

Comment: Then you either did not copy it the right way or you are running the query on different data. I just merged your 2 queries into one.